# create an sbt project in intelliJ 2018.1.4

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I have used intelliJ 2017 version and it allowed to create an sbt project from the menu. Now I upgraded to intelliJ  2018.1.4, and this option is no longer offered.
I installed the sbt and scala plugins but does not make a difference.
any input?

[image]

Comment: check if the scala plugin is enabled and on a curent version in the plugin settings. the sbt plugin is obsolete and not necessary

Comment: yes it's the last version of the plugin which matches with 2018.1.4

Comment: @JustinKaeser thanks, so how do you create an sbt project then in that new edition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to click on `scala`, then there is the option to select `sbt`:

[image]

Comment: Intellij does not support creating default scala projects since 2017.2.1. To vote on whether this feature is to be reintroduced you can vote here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-12478